# AES Execution time measurement

Tags: netbeans, aes, profiler, execution-time

I have used built-in AES-128 in netBeans for encrypting text files. How can i measure the execution time for AES encryption. Is it possible with profiler?

Comment: I don't see why not; have you tried it? You could also log to memory, console or SSD using Guava stopwatch.

Comment: yes, i have tried with profiler. But I  got big values for AES encryption(>200ms).

Comment: That could well be. It depends of course on many things, IO times, run or debug, buffer size, file size,  mode of operation etc. Making comments on timing issues is impossible without lots and lots of info and indeed source code.